# get collection of objects in laravel

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

In a controller, I can do this:

```
$myentity = MyEntity::findOrFail($id);
$collection = MyEntity::where("field", "=", $myentity->value)->get();
```

which gives me a collection of MyEntity objects...

```
dd($collection);
Collection {#331 ▼
  #items: array:11 [▼
    0 => MyEntity {#332 ▶}
    1 => MyEntity {#333 ▶}
    2 => MyEntity {#334 ▶}
    3 => MyEntity {#335 ▶}
    4 => MyEntity {#336 ▶}
    5 => MyEntity {#337 ▶}
    6 => MyEntity {#338 ▶}
    7 => MyEntity {#339 ▶}
    8 => MyEntity {#340 ▶}
    9 => MyEntity {#341 ▶}
    10 => MyEntity {#342 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I need to implement a method inside the Model class that returns the exact same thing but I'm not making it work properly. I've tried something like this:

```
public function test()
{
    return = DB::table("entity")->where("field", "=", $this->value)->get();
}

...

$myentity = MyEntity::findOrFail($id);
$collection = $myentity->test();
dd($collection);
Collection {#319 ▼
  #items: array:10 [▼
    0 => {#309 ▶}
    1 => {#322 ▶}
    2 => {#308 ▶}
    3 => {#320 ▶}
    4 => {#324 ▶}
    5 => {#310 ▶}
    6 => {#315 ▶}
    7 => {#321 ▶}
    8 => {#325 ▶}
    9 => {#326 ▶}
  ]
}
```

How can I get the same result?

Comment: you can't use query builder, that won't give you models ... you have to use the model to do the query, just like you are doing outside the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `DB::table`, the framework doesn't know what PHP class to cast the results to. If you use `MyModel::query()->where('foo', 'bar')->get()`, it should automatically create an instance of `MyModel` for each member of the `Collection`.

Comment: you don't need to call `query()` ...`MyModel::where(....)`  creates the eloquent builder instance dynamically